# What are the differences between x86 CPU operation modes?

Tags: x86, x86-64, mode, bios, uefi

I have read a lot about these operation modes.  but I'm still confused about the differences between these x86 operation modes.

- real mode
- unreal mode
- protected mode
- long mode
- flat mode
- Virtual 8086   mode
- legacy mode

the terms confuse me when reading it in x64 or in 32-bit and 16-bit.  then I get to look for answers for:

is there a 64-bit real mode, a 32-bit real mode or real mode is only termed for a 16-bit?

does UEFI use real mode?

what BIOS-based system (not UEFI) supports long mode?

which mode is for 32-bit? 64-bit? 16-bit?

I am not sure how to organize these in my head.  the closest that help me differentiate these modes are from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_mode.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Operating_modes is a nice table breakdown.  No, there's no 64-bit real mode; putting the CPU into modes other than legacy 8086 compat mode (real mode) with a control-register bit implies that the CS segment value is treated as a selector, and the selected code-segment descriptor tells the CPU what mode to be in.

Comment: Another key thing to keep in mind is that booting an old system (like from mid 2000s) might only support BIOS *booting*, but the bootloader / OS is free to switch to another mode after it's booted.

Comment: UEFI switches to long mode (64-bit mode) and only supports 64-bit bootloaders. No non-UEFI BIOS supports 64-bit mode, as far as I know.

Comment: You may get a better understanding by dropping the 16 vs 32 vs 64 bits things. Modes are not primarily about bitness, they allow for different address sizes though. Download the Intel SDM Volume 3 and read the first chapters, it takes time but it's worth it.

Comment: Thank you so much guys.  I think i know how the modes work now where even a simple segment change or an opcode prefix gets you to a different mode.  I'm still struggling with tagging the terms and definitions but many thanks for the references and info.

Comment: A prefix on a single instruction doesn't change *mode*, it just overrides the operand or address size for that one instruction.  That's a pretty fundamental difference.  e.g. a 32-bit operand-size prefix on `mov ds, eax` in real mode doesn't make the CPU use it as an index into the GDT like it would in protected mode.

Comment: Go to the primary source which is the Intel manual. The -1 manual has a section about processor modes.